# Specflow - How to use FeatureContext in BeforeFeature for Parallel Tests

Tags: specflow

to run tests in parallel you can't use the FeatureContext the way it is (eg: FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title). 
So you have to inject it like the documentation states http://specflow.org/documentation/Parallel-Execution/

But, what if I'm using the FeatureContext in the [BeforeFeature] hook where it HAS to be a static method according to: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks

To exemplify I have this Hook that works fine when not running in parallel:

```
[BeforeFeature]
internal static void BeforeFeature()
{
// Some code here
string title = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;
// More code here
}
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SpecFlow <= 2.1 this is not possible.
With SpecFlow 2.2 we added the ability to get the FeatureContext as parameter. See this PR here https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/pull/779

To use this now, you have to use a version from the CI- feed. A prerelease with it is planning for next week.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!

Comment: Hi Andreas, wouldn't it make sense to also have this for *scenarios*, i.e. ScenarioContext injected for Before/AfterScenario hooks? How else can we access e.g. ScenarioContext's TestError in a parallel execution context? On a side note: wouldn't a pipeline-base approach make the test execution engine a lot easier, both to develop/maintain as well as to use?

Comment: @VincentSels: You can get already the ScenarioContext via Context Injection (see http://specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/ at the end). This worked already in SpecFlow 1.9 and can be used in parallel runs. But to get it also as parameter of the hook is a nice idea. Please file an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow